# simulating one year with simple car

Tags: java

Create a method that loops from 1 to 365 to represent days in a year.  Any even multiple of 7 represents Sunday.  Therefore, day 1 is Monday and day 6 is Saturday.

The car is driven to work and back home on Monday through Friday.  Use the dist parameter as the distance each way.

Every Saturday, the driver checks the oil and changes it if necessary.  She also fills the gas tank without driving.  Assume she lives at a gas station? The car is not driven on Sunday.

No additional messages are printed beyond the ones already embedded in the other methods.

```
public void simulateOneYear(int dist)- see above.
```

I have created the method and it runs well I am just unable to figure out how to add the miles driven to have the total at the end of the year.
Would I simply add dist each time I drive?

This is what I have so far (also I am new to this site so I'm sorry if it doesn't formal well)

```
 public void simulateOneYear (int dist){
     int day = 1;
     for(int i = 1; i < 366; i++){
         if(day != 6 && day != 7){
             this.startEngine();
             this.drive(dist);
             this.stopEngine();
             this.startEngine();
             this.drive(dist);
             this.stopEngine();
         }
         if(day == 6){
             if(this.checkOil){
                 this.changeOil();
             }
             this.addGas(this.TANK_CAPACITY - this.checkGasGauge());
         }

         if(day==7){
              day = 1;
         }
         else {
             day++;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Good. Post your code by [Edit]ing your question.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: This is not an homework-dumping ground, Amita.